# Prevent ui-router to store nested states

Tags: angularjs, navigation, angular-ui-router

is it possibile to prevent ui-router to store all the history of nested states? For example, i have a 'list' state, and 'list.item' nested state. When i click on a item, my url becomes like :

```
http://myurl/list/item/3
```

where 3 is item id. Then i click on next item and url becomes :

```
http://myurl/list/item/4
```

and so on. When i click the "back" button on my browser, i'd like to come back to the state i visited before going to 'list', ignoring all nested states that i get clicking on items. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace option when using $state.go, from the docs:

**location - {boolean=true|string=} - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string, must be "replace", which will update url and also replace last history record.**

I think you can use location false when going to the detail view of the item so the url is not updated.